# android tesseract ocr

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to make android OCR that reads arabic using tesseract and the code in this tutorial  http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/  but every time I modify the code and change training data to arabic the app just shuts down without any error message. my logcat as follow

```
06-25 13:14:02.341: I/DEBUG(31):     bef6ceb4  66206e69  
06-25 13:14:03.331: I/BootReceiver(61): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
06-25 13:14:03.361: D/Zygote(33): Process 335 terminated by signal (11)
06-25 13:14:03.371: I/ActivityManager(61): Process com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple (pid 335) has died.
06-25 13:14:03.371: I/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{4054f8f8 com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple/com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple.SimpleAndroidOCRActivity paused=false}
06-25 13:14:03.441: I/WindowManager(61): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
06-25 13:14:03.641: I/ActivityManager(61): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=6}
06-25 13:14:04.511: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(344): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-25 13:14:06.201: D/dalvikvm(61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 418K, 50% free 4160K/8263K, external 3125K/3903K, paused 77ms
06-25 13:18:06.902: D/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: no, I'm changing the string value from eng to ara and the training data file

Answer (score 0):

You do know that you need eng files besides the arab right?
even though you dont need them for anything they need to be present in your training folder

Comment: Okay, is that enough? last i looked at it, tesseract required it to be present in a folder on your "sdcard"...

Comment: OK but the app worked in english well without copying the data to sdcard